# Sharing Cloud* objects in azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I'm making a simple azure function which should process some collection(for now, by Parallel.ForEach, I want keep it simple, without queues and durable functions) and upload results blobs to azure blob storage. I found in [microsoft azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections#use-static-clients) advice that I should use one static azure client. But, on the other hand I can't find in documentation any information about thread safety Cloud* classes. I understand that I should make CloudBlobClient static. But, can I make CloudBlockContainer static? I have similiar doubts about azure storage files, table storage classes. Which objects should I not share?

Example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage?view=azure-dotnet

Can I make static everything except CloudBlockBlob and upload blobs parallel for example by Parallel.ForEach? Where can I find informations about thread safety these classes? I want to write reliable code.

Comment: Have you tried Output Bindings instead of manual utilization of Storage SDK?

Comment: No, I haven't. I will try, thank you! But my questions are still valid - for education purposes :)